# UITableView load cell image asynchronously with NSURLSession in XCode 7 Swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

Can someone please post sample code on how to display a table view that loads cell images asynchronously?

There are plenty of Stack Overflow questions and blog posts with working sample code for earlier versions of Swift but I can't find any examples compatible with Swift 2.0 and XCode 7.

Comment: currently having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

pinterest has a great library for this
https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage

```
import PINRemoteImage

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let j = MYCELLOBJECT![indexPath.row]
            let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CUSTOMCell.id) as! CUSTOMCell

            c.Icon?.pin_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: j.URLTOIMAGE), placeholderImage: UIImage(), processorKey: "Ball", processor: { (result, cost) -> UIImage! in
              return result.image

                }, completion: { (result) -> Void in })

            return c

    }
```